# Next.js 13.4 App deployed to Cloud Run: Inconsistent behavior of environment variables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, deployment, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I have a Next.js app deployed on Cloud Run, and I'm experiencing issues with environment variables. Most of the time, they work fine, but there are instances when they become undefined. It's strange because there haven't been any new deployments or changes. The same deployment that was previously working fine suddenly has undefined environment variables after a few hours. I've been unable to find a solution to this problem, and it's quite perplexing.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue and found a resolution? Any insights or experiences would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an api endpoint that picked up an env var value baked into the docker image instead of using that configured in Cloud Run. I found that adding this to the api endpoint code solved the problem.

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

I also updated the .dockerignore file to include the .env.local file so this was not included in the docker image.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Adding the .env.local to the .dockerignore was the key for my case, +1